# Variables and Stdout with Curl

Tags: bash, scripts, curl

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) is the interpreter.

I am trying to find a way to test whether a curl request to a host returns a success code (200) BEFORE saving the curl data to file.

This is the best code I could come up with at the moment.

```
flag_output=$(curl -O -w %{http_code} "https://api.genericpath")
```

I plan to write an if flag equals 200, then save to file.

The problem here is curl automatically saves to file.

I tried piping/grep but that doesn't seem to work either.

Do I have to direct the header to a file using --dump-header, then open the file and test whether the http code is 200? Seems pretty inefficient, especially if I am iterating curls.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround build upon what you already have:

```
$ CONTENT=$(curl -w %{http_code} https://git.io)
$ [ $(tail -1 <<<$CONTENT) -eq 200 ] && head -n -1 <<<$CONTENT > output
```

To match what you asked in the comments:

```
$ [ $(tail -c -4 <<<$CONTENT) -eq 200 ] && head -c -4 <<<$CONTENT > output
```

---

What is happening:

- Content includes the HTTP code at the last line.
- Second line says `if` the last line is 200 exclude it from the others and redirect what remains to a file named output.
- You might also want to use `-s` with `curl` to make it silent.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. This gets me halfway there but I think I can figure it out from here.The only problem is the output of the curl command is all on one line so I have to test the last three characters then strip off the last 3 characters and save the data to file. This is an example of the actual output: {"price":"8.84000"}200 –

Comment: @MatthewWeems Updated the answer ;)

Comment: Man, thank you, you are awesome. I knew tail worked for lines but I didn't know it could edit characters.  I'll pay it forward!